# How to print two lists in a new line for each?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to use \n but it gives back an error. Am I using it wrong?

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
list3 = list1 + list2
list4 = [list1 + list2]
print(list3, list4)
```

The result should be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may reach your answer by formatting the string.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
list3 = list1 + list2
list4 = [list1 + list2]
print(f'{list3}\n{list4}')
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Have Fun :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using 'sep':

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
list3 = list1 + list2
list4 = [list1 + list2]
print(list3, list4,sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the arguments like this in print :

```
print(list3,'\n', list4)
```

And the output will be :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Or

```
print(list3)
print(list4)
```

Comment: But now it prints the second list with indentation

Comment: You can use two : print(list3) print(list4) and there will be no indentation

Comment: Why not use the `sep` argument? `print(list3, list4, sep='\n')`

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest solution but you can do the following:

```py
print(list3,'\n'+str(list4))
```